# Facebook App Wall Posting no longer showing in Facebook iPhone App

Tags: python, objective-c, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the GRAPH API with django for Facebook wall postings.  Since yesterday, the wall posts only show on the Facebook web app but not the Facebook iPhone app.  I tried Yelp, and their postings still show up.  How can I debug this?  Anyone notice this issue with their Facebook connect?  Is this a Facebook algorithm issue.

Code for Wall Post:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
        attachment = {"name": name,
             "link": link,
             #"caption": "{*actor*} posted a new review",
             "description": desc,
             "picture": picture }
        graph.put_wall_post("",attachment)
```

Comment: I have the same problem with an iOS app that is already in the app store. Posts are showing only on Facebook desktop/web version. It seems like a general issue they have since even foursquare and Nike+ posts are not showing up on the mobile version.

Comment: When did this start happneing for you? I'll post something on their fbios bug tracker.

Comment: about two days... i just opened a bug for it  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220528154675501 - it seems like a serious issue and it's odd that no one reported it before. as mentioned it affects any app that i checked.

Comment: it seems to be ok now... i checked both my app, 4SQ and yelp and it shows on all interfaces (mobile web, desktop, ios app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. I am writing an iPhone app in Objective C and my post code uses the FBStreamDialog box to prompt for input and then post to a news feed.  So, it appears the problem is more likely to be a Facebook problem rather than a coding problem.

Comment: When did this start happening for you?  Same time?

Comment: Yes same time as you - I had posted links the evening before and they were working fine. I tried the next day and they weren't appearing through either the Android or iPhone FB app and still aren't - I'm trying every day at the moment.

Comment: thanks me too.  i tried yelp and it is still working for them. maybe they are being selective?